# Do I still need to backup AD even with replication to a secondary DC?

Tags: active-directory

At my place of work, we have a small domain just for our development team (6 members). We need this because some products we use in our job require a complete environment which requires AD, ESX/HyperV, etc (no two ways about that).

The AD is syncd with a secondary AD on an ESX Virtual Machine. Despite this level of fault tolerance, does one still need to backup the secondary AD? The primary AD is syncd to secondary so I assume that shouldn't need to be backed up. But then the problem with backing up the secondary AD is that there may be changes on primary which have not been replicated to secondary.

This is a small AD environment, which would probably influence the level of fault tolerance. It's not for production, but for development (though development directly effects when/how projects reach production).

Would backups of AD still need to be executed even with replication? The immediate answer would be no, but I feel there is more to this than I can see.

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about replication latency in AD backups in such a small environment. Just run a "System State" backup every so often on the virtual DC and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 5):

Bottom line: Redundancy is not the same thing as a backup.  Just as RAID does not obviate the need for disk backups, replication does not obviate the need for database backups (or Active Directory backups).

Comment: +1. Redundancy is not backup. Redundancy is not backup. Redundancy is not backup. :)

Comment: +1 Came here to post the same thing

Comment: I had a situation in a Customer site where someone deleted an OU hierarchy containing 2,000+ user accounts (many of which had Exchange mailboxes), all the non-default security groups, and several hundred "contact" objects. Had I not been making backups of Active Directory I would've had *major* problems. In 5 minutes all the DCs in the local site had copies of the deletions (tombstones), and in 15 all the DCs in the organization had them. Reanimating 2,000+ objects would *NOT* have been fun. Doing an authoritative restore took part of an afternoon but averted disaster easily. Backup your AD.

Answer (score 4):

For a small development environment like that, backing up AD would not be required.  In production environments, AD backups are usually just used to protect against accidental changes or catastrophic schema updates.

If you wanted to be cautious, then I would just schedule weekly system state backups with Windows Backup on one of your DCs and store the BKF file on a different server.  There's no need to spend a lot of money on a backup solution.

Comment: +1, came here to say this. Do at least a cheap backup as a handy way of reverting from a bad update etc. Sure, you could rebuild the entire thing, but in this case having the backup saves you the time and hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely backup your domain controller[s].  Having a second DC provides redundancy if one of them fails.  However, if you make a breaking change to AD (to the schema or elsewhere) and this change replicates to your second DC, then both are bad.  A backup would allow you to restore your active directory database to a healthy state on both DC's.  The point here is integrity, and not redundancy.